# How to split a number in Lua

Tags: lua

I have a VFD device which sends the Software (SW) version value as 10103 (via Modbus as U-integers), but the actual SW version is `1.01.03`. How can the value be split and shown as the actual SW version in Lua.

Comment: In this case it will be mostly separated by 3 dots. As far as I know it will be the last 2 digits and the 2 before digits as VFD versions update is very rare

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of what you can do

```
s = "1020304"

a = s:gsub("(%d%d)(%d%d)$",".%1.%2")
print(a) -- 102.03.04

b = s:reverse():gsub("(%d%d)","%1."):reverse():gsub("^%.", "")
print(b) -- 1.02.03.04
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, the last two digits are the patch version, and the two digits before them are the minor version; the rest is the major version. "Selecting" these digits can be achieved either using a bit of string operations or, IMO preferably, using a bit of modulo and floor division:

```lua
local ver = 10103
local patch = ver % 100
ver = ver // 100
local minor = ver % 100
ver = ver // 100
local major = ver
print(("%d.%d.%d"):format(major, minor, patch))
```

if you want to preserve zero padding, use `%d.%02d.%02d` as the pattern